# Using namespace in laravel view

Tags: laravel, view, namespaces

How to use namespace in laravel View? I mean I have three different folders `admin`, `frontend` and `client` in `app/views` folder.
If I want to load a partial template lets say from `admin` section `views/admin/partials/flush.blade.php` in `views/admin/account/profile.blade.php` I have to include it like:

```
@include('admin/partials/flush')
```

instead I want to just use

```
@include('partials/flush')
```

How can i do that?

Comment: you can write your own blade tag that internally calls the blade internal include BUT adds something at the front

Comment: Any example @ITroubs.? Thanks for your response .

Comment: take a look here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade but it might become a real mess...

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend blade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#extending-blade) and write a function that fits your needs. Like this:

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('includeNamespaced');

    $viewPath = realpath($compiler->getPath());
    $parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $viewPath);
    $viewsDirectoryIndex = array_search('views', $parts);
    $namespace = $parts[$viewsDirectoryIndex + 1];

    $php = '$1<?php ';
    $php .= 'if($__env->exists(\''.$namespace.'.\'.$2)){';
    $php .= 'echo $__env->make(\''.$namespace.'.\'.$2)->render();';
    $php .= '}';
    $php .= 'else {';
    $php .= 'echo $__env->make($2)->render();';
    $php .= '}';
    $php .= '?>';

    return preg_replace($pattern, $php, $view);
});
```

And then use it like you described but with `includeNamespaced`

```
@includeNamespaced('partials/flush')
```

If you want to you could also override `@include` by naming it `createMatcher('include')`

**Note** "your" `@includeNamespaced` / `@include` wont have the option to pass arguments to the view your including (second parameter)

**A little tip:** When you change the code inside `Blade::extend` you have to delete the cached views in `storage/views` for the changes to show up in your browser.